# Comparing Database Tables and Deleting Rows in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Table 1

```
id | name

1    alo
2    nemo 
5    gogo
```

Table 2

```
id | object

1    have
2    name
5    lok
4    fan
```

What I am trying to do is deleting the row with the id=4 in table2 because it doesn't exist in table1 1.

How can I do such a comparison, on database tables that have more than 400.000 rows?

Answer (score 8):

```
DELETE FROM table2
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM table1)
```